# Cast Model to ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, automapper

this is my Category model :

```
public class Category :IAggregateRoot
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

and this is my CategoryViewModel :

```
 public class CategoryViewModel
    {
        public Guid  CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and I wanna to cast this Category to CategoryViewModel with Automapper , if I change the CategoryId in CategoryViewModel to Id , it will be OK! but in this case I don't get the Guid value in my controller ! how can I cast these to Guid to each other ??
 and also this is me mapper class :

```
public static CategoryViewModel ConvertToCategoryViewModel(this Category category)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<Category, CategoryViewModel>(category);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

At some point you are probably setting up the auto mapper mapping with a call to

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CategoryModel, CategoryViewModel>();
```

After CreateMap, call

```
.ForMember(m=>m.CategoryId, c=>c.mapfrom(d=>d.Id)).
```

This tells auto mapper to map the categoryId property from the `Id` property.

Edit: the full code would look something like:

```
// in app start
Mapper.CreateMap<CategoryModel, CategoryViewModel>()
    .ForMember(cvm => cvm.CategoryId, c => c.MapFrom(cm => cm.Id));

// in you mapping method:
return Mapper.Map<CategoryModel, CategoryViewModel>(categoryModel);
```

Comment: I Wonder I don't get anything in lambda expression!

Comment: I Use this line of code but I don't get the Id and categoryId in lambda expression!  return Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>().ForMember();

Comment: Can you post the full code you're now trying to use? There should be a createmap+ForMember statement run on app start, and a map call run in your conversion method.